# Condition in value in NLog.config

Tags: nlog

I create my own layout in `NLog.config` file:

```
<variable name="MyLayout" value="${message}: ${exception:format=tostring}"/>
```

But when there is no exception I still see `:`  after message and nothing after it in my log file.

How could I add `:`  only if there is an exception?
Maybe something like this *(not working code)*:

```
<variable name="MyLayout" value="${message}${exception != null ? ': ' : ''}${exception:format=tostring}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [${message}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Message-Layout-Renderer)

`${message:exceptionSeparator= \: :withException=true}`

Or you can use [${onexception}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/OnException-Layout-Renderer)

`${message}${onexception: \: }${exception:format=tostring}`

Notice `:` is used as option-delimiter for NLog LayoutRenderer, so it has to be [escaped](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#content-escaping).